# angular-ui-grid - no gridTestUtils.spec.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, angular-ui-grid

I'm using angular-ui-grid 4.0.2 (the latest version) in my project.

According to the documentation here:
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/403_end_to_end_testing.

There should be some sort of test utilities module available named something like 'gridObjectTestUtils.spec.js' in a folder named 'e2e'.

As far as I can see no such module exists.
Here is a link to the source:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/tree/gh-pages/release/4.0.2

Does anybody know if the testing module is still available? Or has it been deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars.bower/angular-ui-grid which is the same artifact you get from running:

> npm install angular-ui-grid

This package (for whatever reason) does not contain the test utilities.
However if you use:

> npm install angular-ui/ui-grid (unfortunately not available as a webjar)

You get the e2e folder with all the test utils inside!
By the way, I have checked and ui-grid is the same thing as angular-ui-grid.
Also, ui-grid has it's latest commit set in this month of 2017, so it's not an older version. If you want to get the testing utilities, make sure you download ui-grid!

Comment: The utilities are not present because they have not exposed it.
If you have a look at "ui-grid/package.json", you will notice that the test directory has been mentioned inside "directories.test".
As per documentation, "directories.test" should be used for following purpose:
"Put your tests in here. It is currently not exposed, but it might be in the future."
Type "npm help json" in command line for more information.